# Docker volumes blocking start container

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

I am trying to set up keycloak in docker compose.
My Folder structure looks like this:
[image]

where wiremock is a folder for wiremock service. Wiremock1 is exac copy of wiremock and test is just test folder with test files.

```
services:
  wiremock:
    image: wiremock/wiremock
    container_name: wiremock
    volumes:
      - ./wiremock:/home/wiremock
  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - "8090:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./wiremock1/ __files:/tmp

    command:
      - start-dev
```

using for keycloak  `volumes: - ./wiremock:/tmp` works ok.

**but using either test directory or wiremock1 causing that container will not start.**
And i need new volume for keycloak. Not re-using wiremock which is rather obvious.

`volumes: - ./wiremock1:/tmp` not working .

`volumes: - ./test:/tmp` not working.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a space and some underscores in your bind mount volume definition.  You should probably remove that and rename your directory or escape it.  Also I'm not sure relative paths will work with docker-compose.

Maybe try this after renaming your files directory:

```
services:
  wiremock:
    image: wiremock/wiremock
    container_name: wiremock
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/wiremock:/home/wiremock

  keycloak:
    container_name: keycloak
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak
    environment:
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    ports:
      - "8090:8080"
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/wiremock1/files:/tmp

    command:
      - start-dev
```

Comment: I did like you said and still does not working.

Comment: 'docker service ls' will give you the names of the services you are using in your docker-compose.  Once you have the service name for the wiremock service try using the 'docker service inspect' command to determine if there is an error message.

Comment: no able to see logs. Container is creating and there is no logs at all

Comment: I resolved my issue.  
I forced docker desktop to use wsl2 and started to work ok.